# I am writing a code to convert lowercase letters to uppercase letters using arrays

Tags: c++

I have the code but it prints the letters in uppercase but also prints some weird characters afterwards. I just wanted to know how to just get the letters.

the program executing picture.
[image]

using namespace std;

```
int main()
{

const int SIZE = 81;                                                       // Constant for size of an array
const int MIN_LOWERCASE = 97;                                              // Start of lowercase letters in ASCII
const int MAX_LOWERCASE = 122;                                             // End of lowercase letters in ASCII

char line[SIZE];                                                           // Initializing character line for input

cout << "Enter a string of 80 or fewer characters:\n";
cin.getline(line,SIZE);                                                    // Getting input from the user.

for (int count = 0; count < SIZE; count++)
{
    if (line[count] >= MIN_LOWERCASE && line[count] <= MAX_LOWERCASE)     // Checking whether the selected letter is in the reange of lowercase letters.
    {
         line[count] - 32;                                                
         cout << static_cast<char>(line[count] - 32);                     // converting and displaying lowercase letters to uppercase letters.

    }
    else
    {
        cout << static_cast<char>(line[count]);//Displaying the same character if it is in uppercase.                 

    }

}
cout << endl;


system("pause");
return 0;


}
```

Comment: The fist `line[count]-32` has no effect!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the actual size of the text that you read. Else you will print extra characters.

```
for (int count = 0; count < strlen(line); count++)
```

You might need `#include <cstring>` to use `strlen()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
cout << "Enter a string of 80 or fewer characters:\n";
cin.getline(line,SIZE);                                                    // Getting input from the user.
int strLen=strlen(line)
for (int count = 0; count < strLen; count++)
{
    if (line[count] >= MIN_LOWERCASE && line[count] <= MAX_LOWERCASE)     // Checking whether the selected letter is in the reange of lowercase letters.
    {
         line[count] - 32;                                                
         cout << static_cast<char>(line[count] - 32);                     // converting and displaying lowercase letters to uppercase letters.

    }
    else
    {
        cout << static_cast<char>(line[count]);//Displaying the same character if it is in uppercase.                 

    }

}
```

Ypur loop is running 80 times no matter what is the size of string.

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic way of doing this in C++ is

```
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::locale loc(""); //< the current system locale

    std::string line;  //< will contain the input line
    std::cout << "Enter a string of 80 or fewer characters:\n";
    std::getline(std::cin,line);

    std::string lower; //< will contain the output

    // This is the "key" of everything
    std::transform(line.begin(),line.end(), // transform the entire input...
        std::back_inserter(lower), // by writing into the back of the output string ...
        [&loc](auto c){ return std::tolower(c,loc); }); // the result of std::tolower applied to all character, using the system locale

    std::cout << "The transformed string is:\n" << lower << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

// look ma! No pointers, array sizes, overflows and explicit memory management.
// And works consistently with the language your computer is set up.
```

Comment: Surely, it is possible to learn this way before mucking with fixed arrays and all that because this way is closer to the concepts in the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, getline / cin / scanf etc. functions for char[] is explained following example:

- The string is initialized for `char c[10];`. The input is "abcd".
- First, c[i] is initialized **unknown value**, because it is local variable (If it is a global variable, you can assume that c[i] = 0)
- Second, If you input, the value of c[i] only changed where `0<=i<=4` because the length of input is 4.
- In this case, currently `c = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '\0', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?}`. (? denotes unknown value)
- Third, you are looping i for 0 to size_of_array_c, so your output will be "abcd?????" (I don't know the value of ?).

So, you can fix the bug if you only loop while `c[i] != '\0'`.